# Error in Radio Button if not checked

Tags: php

Hello I am a beginner in PHP
I have created a form and there are few radio button with YES/NO options... every thing is working fine but if i submit form without clicking radio button options, it shows the following error... I know there is some code to be written but not getting exactly

```
'Notice: Undefined index: ws_id in D:\xampp\htdocs\mc\db_def.php on line 18'
```

Comment: Please add your PHP code to the question.

Comment: Check using `isset()` before attempting to use the value..

Comment: @Jai no knowledge of js... beginner boss!

Comment: @user3251639 sorry boss! i just missed the tag you have included `php` only. btw check the `name` attribute in your radio btns.

Comment: @Jai name attributes are ok... form is working if i check those radio buttons

Comment: then post the php as Rory suggested.

Comment: HTML CODE    '<tr>
    <td><label>Electricity Bill A/c No.:</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="elec_acc" value="YES">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="elec_acc" value="NO">No</td>
    </tr>' and PHP code is  to INSERT is working fine when i click those buttons... error shows when i left them unchecked.

Comment: If you won't check radio button or checkbox the form won't post it so you will not find these inputs on the $_POST superglobal variable.
Try to `var_dump($_POST);` with checked and unchecked version.
Just check the required form name with `isset()` like this `isset($_POST['ws_id'])`.

Comment: @FoPi i know some code has to be applied to validate the fields... as said i am a beginner and don't have much knowledge, dats y asked u guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Solution in your php use isset() to check
2. Use required in input tag "very basic validation"

   ```
   <label for="input1">1:</label><input type="radio" name="test" id="input1" required value="1" /><br />
   <label for="input2">2:</label><input type="radio" name="test" id="input2" value="2" /><br />
   <label for="input3">3:</label><input type="radio" name="test" id="input3" value="3" /><br />
   ```

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Pw5vQ/

Comment: Thanks. Will appreciate if you mark this question correct and upvote it. Thanks

Comment: well upvote requires 15 reputation... i jst started using stack over flow yesterday!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

If you won't check radio button or checkbox the form won't post it so you will not find these inputs on the $_POST superglobal variable.
Try to `var_dump($_POST);` with checked and unchecked version.
Just check the required form name with `isset()` like this `isset($_POST['ws_id'])`.
If `isset` gives you `false` it means it won't checked.

**Solution 2:**

You can preset the inputs with html attribute `checked="checked"`.

For example:

You would like to check the NO radio button for default:

`<input type="radio" name="ws_id" value="YES"/>Yes`

`<input type="radio" name="ws_id" value="NO" checked="checked"/>No`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are getting this error when first accessing the page, so there is no sent data, so your $_POST['ws_id'] or $_GET['ws_id'] or $_REQUEST['ws_id'] has no value in it as there is no data sent.

Use

```
 if (isset($_POST['id'])) // do what you were doing on line 18
 //or
 if (isset($_GET['id'])) // do what you were doing on line 18
 //or
 if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) // do what you were doing on line 18
```

depending on your choice.